# Orbeon Forms: How to add Multiple Filter Values

Tags: orbeon

How do you add multiple filter values to  a dropdown control:
[image]

Many thanks

PeteA

Comment: That "Reference" column isn't something that comes out-of-the-box with Orbeon Forms. Could it be a customization done by SAP? If so, you might want to ask them, or point them to this question, so they can answer your question. And of course, just let me know if I'm missing something. -Alex

Comment: Thanks Alex - I didn't realise that this is a SAP customisation..